# KDE Discover - You have no authorization to execute this operation (Kubuntu 20.10)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, discover-software-center

I have recently installed Kubuntu 20.10 and since yesterday I am getting following error whenever I am trying to remove or install something from Discover.

> You have no authorization to execute this operation

[image]

Below is the output when I tried to execute it from the Konsole.

```
swapnil@Kubuntu:~$ lsb_release -r
Release:        20.10
swapnil@Kubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux Kubuntu 5.8.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 09:14:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
swapnil@Kubuntu:~$ plasma-discover
qrc:/qml/Feedback.qml:2:1: module "org.kde.userfeedback" is not installed
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "Plasma/Theme"
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "Plasma/LookAndFeel"
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "KWin/Effect"
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "KWin/WindowSwitcher"
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "Plasma/Wallpaper"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/servicemenu.knsrc" because: "Config group not found! Check your KNS3 installation."
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "Plasma/Comic"
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "Plasma/LookAndFeel"
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "KWin/Script"
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/ksysguard.knsrc" because: "Config group not found! Check your KNS3 installation."
kf.newstuff.core: Your configuration file uses an old version of the kpackage support, and should be converted. Please report this to the author of the software you are currently using. The package type, we assume, is "Plasma/Applet"
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x5635b65df320)
QObject::connect(AbstractReviewsBackend, ResourcesModel): invalid nullptr parameter
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Couldn't find a category for  "fwupd-backend"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/private/globaltoolbar/PageRowGlobalToolBarUI.qml:49:9: QML PrivateActionToolButton: Binding loop detected for property "checkable"
Fwupd Error:  Remote  vendor-directory has no cache signature!
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
percentage cannot be calculated
PackageKit error: PackageKit::Transaction::ErrorNotAuthorized "You have no authorization to execute this operation" "Failed to obtain authentication."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by running following command on Konsole.

```
killall chrome-remote-desktop-host
```

Later on, I completely removed the chrome-remote-desktop package from Synaptics. I think, below command should also work if trying to remove from Konsole.

```
sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop
```

Comment: You are right! Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Run discover as a root in terminal:

```
sudo plasma-discover
```